# Создание строки для input при выборе нескольких значений

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Вот так выглядит макет
[image: фильтр]

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Застройщики</label>
  <div class="choose_wrapp">
    <div class="choose-input_wrapp">
      <input class="choose-input" type="text" placeholder="Выберите застройщика" readonly />
    </div>
    <div class="choose_variants">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="checkbox_2">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ch_choose_1" />
          <label for="ch_choose_1"><span>Название застройщика</span> (12)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox_2">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ch_choose_2" />
          <label for="ch_choose_2"><span>Девелопер</span> (18)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox_2">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ch_choose_3" />
          <label for="ch_choose_3"><span>Название застройщика</span> (12)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox_2">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ch_choose_4" />
          <label for="ch_choose_4"><span>Девелопер</span> (18)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox_2">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ch_choose_5" />
          <label for="ch_choose_5"><span>Название застройщика</span> (12)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox_2">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ch_choose_6" />
          <label for="ch_choose_6"><span>Девелопер</span> (18)</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Нужно чтобы значения выбранных чекбоксов попадали в верхнее поле input через запятую с пробелом. Также чтобы при отмене выбора не оставалась в конце запятая.

Comment: В теории, я думаю надо сделать функцию, которая вызывается по событию change и выводит ваш текст. Насчёт запятой с пробелом, можно в интернете скопировать функцию, которая объединяет строки с разделителем (запятая и пробел)

Comment: А какие именно данные, цифры или слова или и то и другое?

Comment: Там только те слова которые есть в ниспадающем списке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так :

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.choose_variants input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(inp => inp.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let arr = [];
  document.querySelectorAll('.choose_variants input[type="checkbox"]:checked').forEach(el => {
    if (el.checked) arr.push(document.querySelector(`[for="${el.id}"]`).textContent);
  });
  document.querySelector('.choose-input_wrapp .choose-input').value = arr.join(', ');
}));
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Застройщики</label>
  <div class="choose_wrapp">
    <div class="choose-input_wrapp">
      <input class="choose-input" type="text" placeholder="Выберите застройщика" readonly style="width:100%;" />
    </div>
    <div class="choose_variants">
      <div class="inner">
        <div class="checkbox_2">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ch_choose_1" />
          <label for="ch_choose_1"><span>Название застройщика</span> (12)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox_2">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ch_choose_2" />
          <label for="ch_choose_2"><span>Девелопер</span> (18)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox_2">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ch_choose_3" />
          <label for="ch_choose_3"><span>Название застройщика</span> (12)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox_2">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ch_choose_4" />
          <label for="ch_choose_4"><span>Девелопер</span> (18)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox_2">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ch_choose_5" />
          <label for="ch_choose_5"><span>Название застройщика</span> (12)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox_2">
          <input type="checkbox" id="ch_choose_6" />
          <label for="ch_choose_6"><span>Девелопер</span> (18)</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает!